# mocha-casperjs: sometimes click/waitForXXX don't work immediately with xpath.

Tags: mocha.js, casperjs

I have been using **mocha-casperjs** for a while now and I noticed that for some reason, sometimes code like:

```
casper.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='login']"));
```

or

```
casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='login']")
```

don't work immediately, but it fails saying:
**xpath selector: //a[normalize-space(text())='login']" still did not exist 5000ms**

After some attempts, it just works, but than it doesn't anymore again.

***It is not an asynchronous problem***, because I use code like:

```
if(casper.exists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='login']"))){
  console.log('I am here');
}
```

to test its presence and this always returns "I am here".

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the problem I was having is related to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007890/how-to-perfectly-isolate-and-clear-environments-between-each-test)
The question I have linked to, led me to further testing and to the solution. All the time my tests were failing, it was because I was actually already logged in, so x("//a[normalize-space(text())='login']") wasn't there obviously.

The fact that the below code returned "I am here", it was because I was doing in the wrong way.

```
if(casper.exists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='login']"))){
  console.log('I am here');
}
```

Another thing I did wrongly that it might help someone and that I totally missed, is that I moved casper.start and casper.run outside describe("", function(){...}) like:

```
casper.start();

describe("", function(){
    it("...", function(){..})
    it("...", function(){..})
});

casper.run(function(){
 test.done();
});
```

I hope this helps someone.

Thanks.